# How to open sublime text from terminal in windows?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, sublimetext3

I have installed my sublime text editor in **d drive** some days ago and i have customized it. and then i have create .bashrc file in users/my-name directory. then i added:

```
alias subl = 'the directory i have copied from the app-properties'
```

but it doesn't work..
when i type

```
subl .
```

it shows me,

```
$ subl .
```

bash: $: command not found

How can I open sublime text editor in git bash.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42zh5.png)

Comment: Did you run command after creating alias: `source .bashrc` ? It's required to run in `users/my-name` directory.

Comment: @MoshiurRahmanRony : _the directory i have copied_ : You can not execute a **directory** . Also, post the exact code you have used to define your alias, instead of just describing what you were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you installed `sublime` in folder `d:\Sublime Text 3`.
In this way you need set correct path for alias in `.bashrc` located in directory `users/my-name`. Please, take note that folder's name can have backspaces.

```
alias subl="/d/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

To apply changes run commands in git bash:

```sh
cd ~
source .bashrc
```

Then you can run `sublime` with command:

```sh
subl .
```

Comment: yeah i have run the command of yours.. But still i am seeing ```bash: subl: command not found```

Comment: ```
 vim .bashrc

rony1@LAPTOP-3119RJCM MINGW64 ~
$ cd ~

rony1@LAPTOP-3119RJCM MINGW64 ~
$ source .bashrc
bash: alias: subl: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: /d/Download/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe: not found
bash: /c/Users/rony1: Is a directory
bash: .bashrc: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: .bashrc: line 18: `.bashrc[+] [unix] (15:01 09/02/2021)                             2,15 All'

rony1@LAPTOP-3119RJCM MINGW64 ~
$ subl .
bash: subl: command not found
```

Comment: @MoshiurRahmanRony Can you show the output of command `cat ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42zh5.png

Comment: @MoshiurRahmanRony Unfortunately, I'm not looking here output of command `cat ~/.bashrc`...

Comment: plz click the link to see the output
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLtm6.png

Comment: You should remove one space before `=` and one space after `=`. See my example.